# Generate UUID Version 2 in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, uuid

I'm about to create a distributed computing environment in Java hosted on aws. I will have several computing nodes and need to generate unique UUIDs (will be used as database keys later on).

As far as I understand the [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) specification says only [UUID Version 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_2_(date-time_and_MAC_address,_DCE_security_version)) is safe for a dce.

Is there any existing implementation in Java?

Comment: The [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) class built into Java can *represent* any Version of UUID (1, 2, 3, 4, and 5) value, but can only *generate* Version 4 values. Generating the other types means either looking for a library or using an external resource such as your database.

Answer (score 2):

If all you care about is randomly generated strings in a distributed environment, you should be able to rely on `UUID.randomUUID()` from [java.util.UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

For e.g., look at the [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) class, that provides high-level abstraction for DynamoDB APIs. For all `@DynamoDBHashKey` fields that are marked as `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey`, it internally uses the above method:

> Marks a partition key or sort key property as being auto-generated. DynamoDBMapper will generate a random [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) when saving these attributes.

If it works for DynamoDB, chances are high that it'll work for you too!

Comment: I think this is what I should use. But how can I get the key after the PutItemRequest? With the java sdk [withReturnValues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/PutItemRequest.html#withReturnValues-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ReturnValue-)  of `PutItemRequest` can only return old values.

Comment: use DynamoDBMapper. it'll return the entire saved object.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick excerpt for a type 1 (not random-based, but rather time-based UUID):

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample App:

```
import com.fasterxml.uuid.EthernetAddress;
import com.fasterxml.uuid.Generators;

/**
 * Java UUID Generator
 *
 */
public class UUIDVersionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    String uuidType1= Generators.timeBasedGenerator(EthernetAddress.fromInterface()).generate().toString();
       System.out.println("UUID=" +uuidType1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Generators.timeBasedGenerator() method will generate type-1 UUID.
It will not generate UUID-2

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it exists, but it is not a good use of resources for most applications.  I spent a while trying to find it, which is why I'm posting a link here:
[Java Practices -> Generating Unique IDs](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56)

It is a significant article, and it does not seem appropriate to simply copy the work to post it here.  In summary, you must generate a random number then use its digest to form an appropriate length string.  Doing this can be time consuming and thus inappropriate for IDs you want to create "on the fly".